# Solutions of $f(x)=f'(x)$ where $f$ is continuous under certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis

This particular question was part of my analysis quiz and I was having a hard time figuring it out.

> Let $f:[0,1] \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be a fixed continuous function such that $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Then how many solutions of equation $f(x)=f'(x)$ are on interval $(0,1)$?

Rolle's theorem implies that there exists a $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(c)=0$. But neither I am able to use it in the question nor think about an alternative approach.

So, Can you please help?

Comment: $f\equiv 0$ satisfies the hypothesis and so does $x(1-x)$. So the number of solutions cannot be determined. Perhaps you have read the problem wrongly. The problem probably asks you to find the number of functions $f$ such that $f(x)=f'(x)$ for all $x$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution $g(x) \colon = e^{-x} \cdot f(x)$ is quite all right, since
$$g'(x) = e^{-x}( f'(x) - f(x)$$

and so $f'(x) = f(x)$ if and only if $g'(x) = 0$.

So now $g(0) =g(1)=0$, so in the interval $(0,1)$ there exists at least one solution of $g'(x) = 0$.  That's all one can say, otherwise their number is not determined.